# Socket.IO how to fire multiple callbacks from server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using simple socket.io functions

```
socket.on('test', function(data, successCallback) {
    successCallback({
        "msg": "fetching ur id"
    });
    successCallback({
        "msg": "fetching ur friends"
    });
});
```

I need to fire sequence of multiple callback calls to the client(what server is doing as a message) but second one never fires, it works fine until first callback...can anyone help?

Comment: Did you solve this problem？

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where did you get that callback signature from, having a hard time finding it in the [socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/)

In any case, you can use [emit](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit) function to achieve what you need

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.sockets.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');
io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');
```

Comment: Dmitry, that works fine with one callback, I am already using that on production sites. This time I needed multiple callbacks & got stuck. Moreover, I don't want to use the emit because I am using angular JS and having a hard time because of the scope of the page where I want to listen and on navigating page again and again...listener keeps duplicating